# Conditional script inclusion depending environment

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-cli-v7

I would like to know if there is a way to configure the scripts section of the angular.json file depending on the environment.

I would like to include a specific script(Myscript.js) only when I'm in the production environment.

```
"scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js",
          "./src/assets/scripts/Myscript.js"
        ]
```

I don't find anything in the doc about that. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you use that variable in your index.html and put script conditionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `scripts` array to your `production` configuration inside the `angular.json`. This is located in

> projects->{projectName}->architect->build->configurations->production

```
"projects": {
  {projectName}: {
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js",
              "./src/assets/scripts/Myscript.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This however does not look if the environment variable is set to true, so if you have more configurations that need this, you can obviously add it there as well.

Comment: seems to be exactly what I wanted to do! But I don't get the point with the extension you talked about. I can create a sub configuration?

Comment: @bAN I've removed that part. Can't find it anywhere in the documentation anymore, nor in the JSON schematics of the angular file. Soo, I guess I thought wrong :)